# Is it possible to perform an action after blocking a request using the declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I migrate my extension to manifest v3. I need to keep track of how many requests will be blocked according to my rules. 
How can I get this information?

Comment: There's no way. You can suggest implementing it on https://crbug.com.

Comment: You can get blocked requests with chrome.declarativeNetRequest.onRuleMatchedDebug.

Answer (score 0):

You can get blocked requests with chrome.declarativeNetRequest.onRuleMatchedDebug.

[Link to documentation.](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#event-onRuleMatchedDebug)

Thanks to @NorioYamamoto!